# Posting byte array to the server

Tags: c#

I am using POST to sent a byte array and a string to the server but is not sucessfull, am I doing the right thing?

memStream.Write(image, 0, signature.Length);, image is a byte array.

Code:

```
Uri wsHost = new Uri(WebServices.RESTEnpointAddress());
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wsHost);

                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");

                // Boundary
                var boundary = "------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

                // Set the request type
                request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                //request.ContentLength = docByte.Length;

                // Create a new memory stream
                Stream memStream = new MemoryStream();

                // Boundary in bytes
                byte[] boundaryByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

                // body
                memStream.Write(boundaryByte, 0, boundaryByte.Length);
                string ImgBody = string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n", "signImg", "tmpSignImgName");
                ImgBody += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
                byte[] ImgBodyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ImgBody);
                memStream.Write(ImgBodyByte, 0, ImgBodyByte.Length);
                memStream.Write(image, 0, signature.Length); // image ss a byte array
                memStream.Write(boundaryByte, 0, boundaryByte.Length);

                string signLocLatBody = string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n", "signloclat");
                signLocLatBody += latitude;
                byte[] signLocLatBodyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signLocLatBody);
                memStream.Write(signLocLatBodyByte, 0, signLocLatBodyByte.Length);
                memStream.Write(boundaryByte, 0, boundaryByte.Length);

                Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                memStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
                memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                memStream.Close();
                stream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                stream.Close();
```

Comment: `WebClient.UploadData` or `WebClient.UploadFile` is simpler to use.

Comment: "but is not successful"... what happens? have you looked at it in fiddler etc to see what happens? Have you compared the raw http from successful (via browser) and unsuccessful posts?

Comment: @L.B. not sure that works for multipart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
     byte[] boundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");

     HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(MyUrl);

     webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
     webRequest.Method = "POST";


     using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
     {
              // write boundary bytes
              requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);

              // write header bytes.
              string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
              string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "MyName", "MyFileName", "content type");
              byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
              requestStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

              using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
              {
                      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                      int bytesRead = 0;
                      while ((bytesRead = memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                      {
                              requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                      }
               }

               // write trailing boundary bytes.
               byte[] trailerBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
               requestStream.Write(trailerBytes, 0, trailerBytes.Length);

       }

       using (HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
       {
               using (Stream response = wr.GetResponseStream())
               {
                    // handle response stream.
               }
       }
```

This reads a MemoryStream and writes the data to the requestStream, with a 4096 byte buffer. This should be wrapped in a try-catch so it can trap exceptions and handle them.

Comment: I am sending both byte array(image) and a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use `WebRequest` for Posting data as :

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("MyURL"); 
request.Method = "POST"; 
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
request.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; 


//Here is the Business end of the code... 
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream (); 
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 
dataStream.Close (); 
//and here is the response. 
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse (); 

//Writing response from server

dataStream = response.GetResponseStream (); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream); 
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd (); 
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer); 
reader.Close (); 
dataStream.Close (); 
response.Close ();
```

Comment: Usually I use that to post image, but now I am sending a byte array and a string field.

Answer (score 0):

You need use memStream as a reference to the request stream e.g.

```
Stream memStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

Then when you write to it you are writing to the request.

Comment: No, `memStream` is the buffered data that the OP wants to copy to `stream`