# REST Webservices in c# with json

Tags: c#, service, json.net

i have this json data example

```
http://84.235.49.85:58/saws/hi/is/inserSer?jsonObject={
    "authObject":{
        "userName":"1111",
        "password":"123",
        "baladyCode":"11",
        "amanaCode":"061"
        },
    "billObj":{
        "billNumber":"0611138000302",
        "billCreationDate":"07-01-1438",
        "billDetails":[
                {"depId":"11006","billValue":"1"}
        ]}
}
```

authObject Obj:-
    this object holds authentication data about user that will be used to decide can we allow accessing for this request or not.

billObj Obj:- 
    this object holds bill data that will be used to create insertion operation, let us say that every bill may have one sub-account or many sub-accounts so we make it dynamic and give you to create Json Array of bill's details that holds every sub-account and its value.

i make this code in c# using json.net for insert data in server

```
inserSerJSON jsonclass = new inserSerJSON();
            jsonclass.authObject = new AuthObject();
            jsonclass.authObject.userName = "7070";
            jsonclass.authObject.password = "123";
            jsonclass.authObject.baladyCode = "07";
            jsonclass.authObject.amanaCode = "061";

            jsonclass.billObj = new BillObj();
            jsonclass.billObj.billNumber = txtBillNum.Text.Trim();
            jsonclass.billObj.billCreationDate = myStatic.hdminus(dateINBillDateHig);



            bill[] billclass = new bill[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                billclass[i] = new bill();
                billclass[i].depId = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SubAccount"].Value.ToString();
                billclass[i].billValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString();
            }
            jsonclass.billObj.billDetails = billclass;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();


            string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonclass);
            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output);


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://84.235.49.85:58/saws/hi/is/inserSer");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentLength = toBytes.Length;
            request.ContentType = @"application/json";
            using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(toBytes, 0, toBytes.Length);
            }
            long length = 0;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                length = response.ContentLength;
            }
```

it give me exception in this line

```
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
```

Additional information: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

i change

```
request.Method = "GET" from get to Post
```

the good works fine put give me exception in response line

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()
```

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

please help me to me to solve this problem

Comment: Please clarify "the good works fine put give me exception in response line"

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: But you're sending plaintext usr/pw over HTTP...

Comment: yes this is all exception that occurse > please help me

Comment: exact username 7070 and password 123 > any one can test the code and see the results . and baladyCode:07

Comment: You need to change your `ContentType`.  See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972400/posting-byte-array-to-the-server

Comment: whice type of ContentType . that i have to add > i see this in your line   request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; . test it same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restful API / web service (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) does not allow you to insert / create record with a GET or a PUT method.

You need to use the POST method to be able to create or insert a record.

Another link for reference: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-restful/

Comment: i see it but doing until now same exceptions

Comment: The response headers clearly show that the methods allowed are: GET,OPTIONS,HEAD. You need to talk/contact the person who owns/supports the API for documentation. The API seems buggy. Two concerns: 1) A Restful API that only allows GET method cannot support create/insert record. 2) The security mechanism is insecure. I'm surprised that they are expecting credentials in the body instead of using HTTP basic auth OR token based security.