# C# HttpWebRequest Keep Encode Spaces with '+' When Sending Form Data

Tags: c#, encoding, http-post, httpwebrequest, urlencode

I have a small code that sends a form data using the HttpWebRequest, the problem is, every space is replaced with '+'. How to use %20 as a replacement?

I've tried Uri.EscapeUriString("hello world") & WebUtility.UrlEncode("hello world"), but spaces still replaced with %2b which is still '+'. I also tried to replace it with Replace("+"," "), Replace("%2b","%20"), Replace("+", "%20"). Still no success

```
string TXT_TO_SEND = "Hello beautiful world";

var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] bytes = null;
NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
outgoingQueryString.Add("message", TXT_TO_SEND);
string postdata = outgoingQueryString.ToString();
bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);

string url = "https://my.blog/"

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var response_reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How to make the code above use %20 as a space replacement?

Comment: `Uri.EscapeUriString("hello world")` returns `"hello%20world"`.

Comment: It returns "hello%2bworld"

Comment: if you don't need your queryString to be encoded automatically, just don't use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`, and instead, replace the spaces manually and then assign it to the `postdata`.

Comment: example `string TXT_TO_SEND = "?message=Hello beautiful world".Replace(" ", "%20");` and then `bytes = encoding.GetBytes(TXT_TO_SEND);`

Comment: It returns `hello%20world` :)

Comment: `%2b = 43 = +`. You have encoded: `Uri.EscapeUriString("hello+world")`

Comment: @iSR5 Your answer really helps me Thank you!

Comment: i cant do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798466/c-sharp-upload-image-to-pinterest-with-httpwebrequest/66205348#66205348 can u help